How to customize WP_Error (REST JWT authentication plugin)
 Background & Environment









WordPress
6.6.2


JWT Authentication plugin
1.3.4


Php
8.3



I'm using the recommended plugin JWT authentication for WP REST API, to authenticate my users.
Asking /wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token to generate a new token, I see these 2 error responses:
{
  “code": ‘[jwt_auth] incorrect_password’,
  “message“:”<strong>Error:</strong> The password you entered for the <strong>root</strong> username is incorrect. <a href=” http:\N/\N/localhost:8096\N/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword\N ‘>Your password is lost?<a>’,
  “data": {
    “status” : 403
  }
}

{
  “code": ‘[jwt_auth] invalid_username’,
  “message” : ”<strong>Error:<\/strong> The username <strong>rot<\/strong> is not registered on this site. If you're not sure of your username, try your e-mail address instead”,
  “data": {
    “status": 403
  }
}

⛔ My problem
I want to increase security against brute force so: how to prevent and customize code and message to not display the current failure entry (invalid_username, incorrect_password).
Which filter or action should I use?
‍♂️ Expected
I want an object like the one in the documentation (and also translate the error message to my language ):
{
    "code": "jwt_auth_failed",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    },
    "message": "Invalid Credentials."
}

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions ❤️

Edit: 13/11/2024
Official documentation: REST Handbook - Authentication Plugins

questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here, can you link to where the recommendation is made? There are official methods of authenticating with the REST API, as well as official 1st party OAuth implementations, don't mistake a mention in the docs for a recommendation.

Those look like errors generated by JWT Auth; check with their support team and/or documentation to see if there's a way to modify them.

@TomJNowell • I've added the link to the documentation to my message

@PatJ • I've already checked the documentation and no hook is provided to handle the error response.
I need a Wordpress hook to catch REST errors with the associated endpoint.

that's not a recommendation, just an example, you need to raise this in that plugins support forum or ask somewhere with a more general scope like stackoverflow

✨ Solution
I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to use rest_post_dispatch (documentation) for this purpose (maybe overkill but I didn't found  other way).
It works as expected.
add_filter("rest_post_dispatch", "rest_customize_result", 10, 3);

function rest_customize_result(
  WP_REST_Response $result,
  WP_REST_Server $server,
  WP_REST_Request $request
) {
  if ( $request->get_route() === "/jwt-auth/v1/token"
       && $result->get_status() === 403 ) {
    $data = $result->get_data();
    $data["code"] = "jwt_auth_failed";
    $data["message"] = __("Invalid Credentials.", "theme");
    $result->set_data($data);
  }
  return $result;
}

